# dimension of intersection of subspaces with given dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

Given are two subspaces $U$ and $W$ of subspace $V.$

\begin{align}
\dim(V) & = 7 \\ \dim(U) & = 4 \\ \dim(W) & = 5
\end{align}

what is the dimension of $U \cap W$ ?
I know that the Dimension of subspaces cannot be bigger then the one containing them.
I also know that $\dim(U+W) = \dim U + \dim W - \dim(U \cap W)$
so I'm assuming that the intersection will be small or equal to $4$ on one end since thats the size of the smaller of $U$ and $W$ but I'm not sure about the the other end.

Comment: yes but I need the dimension of (U∩W)

Comment: Thinking maybe 2≤(U∩W)≤4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very much on the right track. If you put together the following two facts:
$$\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W)$$
and
$$\dim(U+W)\le\dim(V)=7,$$
you'll get an inequality that will give you the least possible value for $\dim(U\cap W)$. So the answer will be that
$$\cdots\le\dim(U\cap W)\le4,$$
where you just need to find that lower number.

Comment: is it dim(U+W) - dim(V)? so 2?

Comment: @eventhorizon02: Yes, it's $2$. However, not as the result of "$\dim(U+W)-\dim(V)$", but as the result of $\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(V)$.